# jQuery, function .html correct syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery

Somehow I ran into a syntax problem. I have this code here

```
$('#logoutput').html("<div id=\"loginbox\" class=\"boxgrid\">Username: <form action=\"\" method=\"post\"><input class=\"textfieldcss\" type=\"text\" name=\"loginname\" value="+$userip+"\">Password: <form action=\"\" method=\"post\"><input class=\"textfieldcss\" type=\"hidden\" name=\"loginpass\" value="+$userpw+"\"></div>");
```

if the content only is:

```
$('#logoutput').html("<div id=\"loginbox\" class=\"boxgrid\">Username: <form action=\"\" method=\"post\"><input class=\"textfieldcss\" type=\"text\" name=\"loginname\">"
```

it doesn't show me an error.

Could this be because I implemented the variables wrong into the jQuery function?

Comment: Are $userpw and $userip defined ? Which error you got ?

Comment: step 1: open a text editor, take the code you're pumping into `html()`, and turn it into normal HTML code without all those `\"`. You'll find your typo pretty quickly. With that said, don't build structured content this way, use a templating solution.

Comment: Please remove "[solved]" from your title, it is not necessary on Stack Overflow. If your problem was solved by somebody's answer, please mark that answer as accepted. If you came up with this answer yourself, please write it up as an answer in the answers section (not as part of the question); you can also mark it as accepted if you want.

Comment: if someone could tell me how that would be great

Comment: That would be the [edit] button. I went ahead and fixed a couple of spelling issues as I was there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a true answer to your question, but it'll help you make this far less problematic: don't use strings like this. At the very least use a template. There are lots of libraries that do templating for you, but at least do something like:

```
<script type="text/html" id="mooTemplate">
  <div id="loginbox" class="boxgrid">
    Username:
    <form action="" method="post">
    <input class="textfieldcss" type="text" name="loginname" value="{{ userip }}">
    Password:
    <form action="" method="post">
    <input class="textfieldcss" type="hidden" name="loginpass" value="{{ userpw }}">
  </div>
</script>
```

And then swap it in:

```
var templateHTML = $("#mooTemplate").text()
                   .replace(/{{ userip }}/, userip)
                   .replace(/{{ userpw }}/, userpw);
$(target).html(templateHTML);
```

Although again, don't roll this yourself, just use one of the many premade templating solutions available on the web. I personally like nunjucks, but there are tons of others.

Comment: thanks for the answer i'll look into it so i can implement it your way, definitely makes things easier

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/nvLwzrdp/) seems to work:

```
$('#logoutput').html('<div id=\"loginbox\" class=\"boxgrid\">Username: <form action=\"\" method=\"post\"><input class=\"textfieldcss\" type=\"text\" name=\"loginname\" value="'+$userip+'"\">Password: <form action=\"\" method=\"post\"><input class=\"textfieldcss\" type=\"hidden\" name=\"loginpass\" value='+$userpw+'"\"></div>');
```

Comment: screw those tiny little '+ shoulda ran with them first instead of doing evrything double quotes lol